# Win Form App, Where the database is being saved in general after install?

Tags: c#, database

When I install my newly deployed windows form application on a client computer where my application database is being saved? My app first install SQL server 2008 to complete installation.

In the `Appdata` folder there are only default databases. Although my application is running fine but there is no `.mdf` file of my database name. I want to know where my data is being saved then?

my deployed fodler:[image: Deployed folder]
my Application files folder:[image: Application Files]

Did my deploy is correct?

Comment: Check your SQL server config. If you attached the DB, it should be there.

Comment: Sorry i can't understand what do you mean by SQL server config? Actually i am new so if u please describe in details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database for windows form application with sql compact database is saved on 
`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0` folder

Answer (score 1):

The last time I used localDB in an entity framework app the .mdf files were being saved directly in the `C:\Users\<username>` directory.

Answer (score 0):

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

> The system database files for the database are stored in the users'
>   local AppData path which is normally hidden. For example
>   C:\Users--user--\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local
>   DB\Instances\LocalDBApp1. User database files are stored where the
>   user designates, typically somewhere in the C:\Users\Documents\ folder.

Comment: In C:\Users\Documents\ I have no folder named SQL Server. But In my project folder i have my datbase file. But when i install my app on other computer where my database will save?

Comment: Take a look at the folders and files within the path described above and see if your MDF was copied there:

C:\Users\<YOURUSERNAME>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\

Comment: In my client computer there is no folder named `Microsoft SQL Server Local DB` in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\ folder. But in my pc i have it but there is two folder `v11.0` and `projects`. where only default databases are stored not my custom database for my application

Comment: In my client pc these folder have C:\Users\Nozibulla.Bashar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS but with only default databases. But my App is working fine. I dont know i am using the correct way to deploy. I just publish my app from my solution property option